# Find records where year-month is between the specified year-month pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My data looks like this:

[image: image1]

I want to select rows where year and month is between **11/2015** and **02/2016**. I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM traffic 
WHERE year between '2015' AND '2016'
  AND month between '11' AND '01'
  AND toll_id='14';
```

But the result doesn't print. The expected output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm8hX.png). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add the structure of `traffic` and a clear definition of what you mean by **print**.

Comment: if year,month are integer type then you can directly use number instead of strings like this `'2015'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
-- The (Y1, M1) pair must be less than or equal to (Y2, M2)

SET @Y1 = 2014;
SET @M1 = 11;
SET @Y2 = 2016;
SET @M2 = 1;

SELECT *
FROM traffic
WHERE
    toll_id = 14 
    AND @Y1 <= `year` AND `year` <= @Y2 
    AND NOT (
        (@Y1 = `year` AND `month` < @M1) OR
        (@Y2 = `year` AND `month` > @M2)
    )
```

It simply returns the rows where the year is within desired range **minus** those rows where year is same as start year but month is less than start month or year is same as end year but month is greater than end month.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05c54/5)

Answer (score 0):

select * from traffic where (year=2015 and month>=11) or (year=2016 and month<=2) AND toll_id='14'

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the column names, because year and month are functions in mysql.

```
select *
from traffic
where toll_id = 14 and `month` between 11 and 12 and `year` = 2015 or toll_id = 14 and `month` between 1 and 2 and `year` = 2016 ;
```

or even better use a datetime field (assue the column is called "created_at"):

```
select *
from traffic
where toll_id = 14 and month(created_at) between 11 and 12 and year(created_at) = 2015 or toll_id = 14 and month(created_at) between 1 and 2 and year(created_at) = 2016;
```

Also take care about what's inlcuded and what's exclude when using between. The last one may be excluded.

Edit: Due to definition change in the question, I also changed the answer. Now you have two completely different conditions in where clause. You need the full condition again to check against 1 and 2 from 2016, because the `or` breaks your whole condition. **If you don't, you would see more unexcepted results**. I tested the datetime query sucessfully on my mysql database. So, the other query also works, **because the condition is the same**.

Comment: AFAIK, `BETWEEN` does not work if arguments are not specified in correct order.

Comment: well, yes, I changed this. And I also changed the values to integers, because you can use integer values here. I was not sure if it means from november until january next year. Then we have to change the whole query.

Comment: first query doesn't work because `month` between 11 and 1 
it is work when `month` between 1 and 11 but i dont want this.
.
i want output is

toll_id          month         year         car
14                  11             2015       12025
14                  12            2015        21025
14                  01            2016       150245 
14                  02           2016         25024

Comment: ok, I changed the answer to match your change of your question definition. See my answer. It works now 100%

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'created_at' in 'where clause'

Comment: thanks sir
but my problem solved 
this mehtod

-- The (Y1, M1) pair must be less than or equal to (Y2, M2)

SET @Y1 = 2014;
SET @M1 = 11;
SET @Y2 = 2016;
SET @M2 = 1;

SELECT *
FROM traffic
WHERE
    toll_id = 14 
    AND @Y1 <= `year` AND `year` <= @Y2 
    AND NOT (
        (@Y1 = `year` AND `month` < @M1) OR
        (@Y2 = `year` AND `month` > @M2)
    )